# Aggregating data using a junction table with duplicate entries in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, database-design

I’m designing a data model for my simple MySQL database and am having trouble figuring out the relationship between incoming client payments and invoices.

My goal is building the query that aggregates amounts for payments and invoices as shown below so that I can calculate bank fees among other things.

￼[image]

**Query**

```
select payment_id, amount as payment_total,  sum(invoice_total) as invoice_total, 
sum(invoice_total) - amount as commission from payments 
join invoices_payments using(payment_id)
join invoices using(invoice_id)
group by payment_id;
```

When I was researching legacy data that needs to be imported into the database I discovered that both invoices and payments have a two-way relationship that doesn’t seem to favor one-sided data aggregation (more on that below).

As a rule, a single payment from a client corresponds to a single invoice.  Initially, my plan was to link payments and invoices tables using **invoice_id** as a foreign key:

[image]

I could have a trigger fire each time a new record was added to the *payments* table and update the **payment_total** field in the *invoices* table accordingly.

Back to my data.
After studying historical data more closely, I realised that sometimes a single payment covered multiple invoices.
Say, I sent two invoices of $250 and $350 to a single customer and  they made a one-off payment of $600  covering both ones.

This meant I could no longer use the 1:1 relationship and needed to join payments and invoices via junction table below

*invoices_payments junction table*

￼[image]

After creating a junction table, I discovered a single instance in my data where two individual payments went toward a single invoice. To reverse the previous example, an invoice totalling $600 can have a payments of $250 and $350 paid toward it.

This meant I could no longer reliably use the query above for data aggregation.

When multiple invoices are paid with one payment, I can simply sum **invoice_total** values for that payment, group by **payment_id**, and display the result in a single record.
When one invoice is split into several payments, the result is displayed like this:

[image]

If I do the grouping by **invoice_id** and sum **payment_total** instead, it would work for that single row but then data will be skewed for the one-payment-many-invoices scenario.

Is there a way to handle this situation with another query or by remodelling data relationship but without multiplying entities?  I’m sure the one-invoice-many-payments is an oddball scenario that won't repeat itself so I really don't want to let go of the Occam's razor if possible.

New to MySQL so that could very well be a newbie question.

Comment: You have a payments table, and an invoice table.  Since you require many-to-many relations both ways, you have to create a link table between the two where each line is a foreign key reference to the two tables.  That will allow you to build reports of payments vs invoices.

Comment: If you are looking for running totals, you need MySQL 8 or MariaDB 10.2; they have "windowing functions".

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre]

Comment: @Nic3500 if I do that, the query that sums up all invoices for a given payment will produce false data for cases where multiple payments were made toward one invoice

Comment: I guess you didn't read the answer, and "data" is in the question title. Please use text for what can be given as text & the reasons are given. Moreover a [mre] needs executable initialization. (There's also an editor format for tables that aren't code, though for simple text content it adds a lot of space.) An ERD is a picture of DDL. [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)
I'm done.

Comment: You have a table that links invoices and payments.  So select the paymentid from that table where invoiceid = SOMETHING.  Than sum the payments.